# "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" Android chromium

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, wordpress, chromium

Jquery in my app not working well!!

```
webView.loadData(String.format(htmlText, post.getContent()), "text/html", null);

String str = "";

str = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/scrollblog/js/couraselcss.css' />" +
        "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
        "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js'></script>" +
      "<script src='http://mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/scrollblog/js/jquery.touchcarousel-1.1.min.js'></script>" +
```

in the log:

I/chromium(31613): [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined", source: http://mysite.it/wp-content/themes/tiny-forge/customSelect/script2.js (3)

why?

Answer (score 0):

If you look inside the string concatenation it may hold the answer as to why. You are missing a closing `</script>` tag in the second line. Replace it with the following and things might just work.

```
str = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/scrollblog/js/couraselcss.css' />" +
      "<script type='text/javascript'></script>" +
      "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js'></script>" +
      "<script src='http://mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/scrollblog/js/jquery.touchcarousel-1.1.min.js'></script>" +
```

Comment: nothing has changed !!! appears to be the initial screen of jquery and at the bottom of the page that should be displayed after the click

Comment: And by nothing has changed you mean nothing has changed after replacing the string?

Comment: Can you show some more code? What's happening with the `str`? I am unable to open the link in your question.

Comment: Apart from non-standard HTML usage, looks to be okay. Could you try this - http://pastebin.com/wGPNagsg

Comment: There's something more happening here. Where does the html generated from this method go? How are you loading it in the WebView?